# NavigationView различные itemTextColor

Tags: android

Имеется `NavigationView` в котором подключаю `menu` c `items`.

Можно ли как то задать что бы цвет например первого элемента был белый, а второго синий?

Т.е. не при нажатии а статически цвета `items` были разные.

**NavigationView.xml**:

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation_items"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/my_text_color">
```

Меню:

```
<menu>
    <item
    android:id="@+id/my_id1"
    android:title="Элемент1"/> 

    <item
    android:id="@+id/my_id2"
    android:title="Элемент2"/>

</menu>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я согласен с @ЮрийСПб абсолютно, просто предложу грязный и менее грязный хак, эту мысль можно развить, вот примеры:

### Пример-1:

Находим NavigationView , вытаскиваем Menu потом нужный Item, и красим в коде сам текст. Можно через UTF-16 сделать кстати я никогда такого не пробовал, уверен что можно, в целом мысль ясна.

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
navigationView.getMenu().getItem(1).setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#fff'>NotLikeAll</font>"));
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

### Пример-2:

Находим NavigationView, из Menu вытаскиваем нужный MenuItem (второй), используем класс SpannableString и метод setSpan, он ждет Object. Скармливаем ему ForegroundColorSpan и это более лояльно, ибо он расширен CharStyle, который имеет Paint для раскраски, поэтому обратная генерация кода в UTF-16 будет на сознании AndroidSDK, и от этого вроде легче, ну чуть чуть... наверно..)

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

MenuItem item_1 = navigationView.getMenu().getItem(1);
SpannableString s = new SpannableString(item_1.getTitle());
s.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.GREEN), 0, s.length(), 0);
item_1.setTitle(s);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

Простого способа из коробки нет. Вы можете задать только значения для всех элементов сразу.

Придётся программно брать каждый элемент в onPrepareOptionsMenu по их ID и назначать там.

Плюс попробуйте посмотреть [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33212331/3212712). Говорят, что можно собственную разметку для каждого элемента назначить - так будет ещё больше контроля. Но кода всё одно будет порядочно.

Comment: странно что он такой не обдуманный так много кода  иза малого

Comment: @elik, просто он так задуман. В общем случае не предполагается что кто-то будет делать пункты разным цветом. Это, вроде как, не совсем по дизайну, продвигаемому гуглом.

Comment: @elik, если вам совсем закастомизировать там всё надо, то лучше взять и сделать свой список чрез RecyclerView/ListView чем пытаться изменить NavigationView

Comment: понятно спасибо)всеже всем не угодишь )

Answer (score 1):

Долго искал способ динамически подменивать цвет текста (и иконок), в зависимости от темы. Сейчас использую такой способ сразу для всех пунктов. Ничего не мешает использовать его и по-штучно. Из преимуществ - сразу задаем любой цвет для любого состояния (нажато/выделено/выбрано/неактивно).

```
     int[][] states = new int[][]{
            new int[]{-android.R.attr.state_checked}, // default
            new int[]{android.R.attr.state_checked}  // checked
    };

    int[] colors = new int[]{
            AppConst.color_text_small,
            AppConst.color_accent
    };

    ColorStateList color_menu_item = new ColorStateList(states, colors);

    navigationView.setItemTextColor(color_menu_item);
    navigationView.setItemIconTintList(color_menu_item);
```

Comment: Что такое AppConst? `int[] colors = new int[]{ AppConst.color_text_small, AppConst.color_accent`.